# strlen doesn't return the correct value with pointer to an array

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
char* realtor_command[120];
for(int i=0;i<REALTOR_MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH;i++){
    realtor_command[i]=malloc(sizeof(120));
}
realtor_command[0]="test_string"
realtor_command[1]="next_test_string"
```

When I use `strlen(realtor_command[0])` I get wrong value, I read in previous questions this happens because its an array and not pointer, yet I haven't found any fix for this problem.

My question is if there is anyway to get the length of `realtor_command[i]`?

Thank you very much.

EDIT :

This is how I invoke strlen :

```
char* matrix=malloc(strlen(realtor_command[8])+1);
```

Comment: Show how you invoke `strlen`, please, together with the wrong value.

Comment: What the heck is `sizeof(120)`?? You're allocating _much less_ memory than 120 bytes.

Comment: That would be sizeof(int), either 4 or 8.

Comment: @JaVaPG what result are you getting?

Comment: Just so you know, this code should be `for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {` (since the array is 120 strings) and you should probably be doing something different than `malloc` since you're leaking memory inside that loop. Basically, you're allocating `sizeof(int)` bytes of data (4-8 bytes), but then after your loop you're changing the pointer to point to a new string ("test_string"), so you never use the data you allocated.

Comment: @Downvoter Edited.

Comment: how do you assign null-terminated string to realtor_command[0]?

Comment: I'm aware of the memory leaking this is just an example.

Comment: @JaVaPG, how much memory do you need for each string: 120 bytes?

Comment: @JaVaPG: if you show minimal code wich reproduce the problem, you will get right point how to solve it.

Comment: `strlen` does not take a "pointer to an array", but "pointer to `char`". Luckily your code does poass this one. Anyway: provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
char* realtor_command[120];
for(int i=0;i<REALTOR_MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH;i++){
    realtor_command[i]=malloc(sizeof(120));
}
```

You create an array of 120 strings, then loop through `REALTOR_MAX_COMMAND` strings (presumably this should be 120?) and set them to newly allocated 4- or 8-byte strings (`sizeof(120)` means `sizeof(int)` which is either 4 or 8 bytes). Since those strings are newly allocated, they will contain arbitrary data, and may not end with a null-terminator.

This is important because `strlen()` just loops over the string until it finds a null terminator, so it can't work with non-null-terminated strings.

You could add a null terminator yourself, but then the strings would contain arbitrary garbage up to the end of the string, and they may have null terminators inside them. You could make them start with a null-terminator, but then `strlen()` would always return 0.

What might be better is to allocate these strings when you actually fill them, and leave them as null pointers until then:

```
char* realtor_command[120];
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
    realtor_command[i] = NULL;
}

char input_buffer[REALTOR_MAX_COMMAND];

// Read in one string, then copy it so we can re-use the buffer
fgets(input_buffer, REALTOR_MAX_COMMAND, stdin);
realtor_command[0] = strdup(input_buffer);
```

This will also avoid the memory leak in your code.

Note that you'll probably want to make sure the string read by [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) contains a newline, to make sure the input fit in your buffer:

```
if (strstr(input_buffer, "\n") == NULL) {
    // error, input didn't fit in our buffer!
}
```